# SQL: Selecting data from multiple tables with multiple records to select and join

Tags: sql

I have three tables: VolunteerRelationships, Organizations, and CampaignDates. I'm trying to write a query that will give me the organization id and name, and the org's start and end campaign dates for the current campaign year <@CampaignYear>, based on the selected volunteer <@SelectedInd>.

Dates are stored as separate column values for day, month and year which I'm trying to cast into a more an formatted date value. If I can get this, I'd also like to use a case statement to get the status of the campaign based on whether the date campaign dates are upcoming, currently running, or already closed, but need to get the first part of the query first.

Sorry if I'm leaving a lot of needed info out, this is my first time posting a question to this forumn. Thank you!

```
VolunteerRelationships
id | name | managesId |expiryDate
1  | john | 1         |
2  | jack | 2         |6/30/2020
3  | jerry| 3         |12/31/2021

Organizations
 id | name1 
 1  | ACME

CampaignDates
orgId | dateDay | dateMonth | dateYear | dateType | Campaign Year
1     | 5       | 11        | 2020     | Start    | 2020
1     | 15      | 11        | 2020     | End      | 2020

Result
    orgId | orgName | startDate | endDate    | Status 
    1     | ACME    | 2020-01-01| 2020-01-15 | Closed 




select 
v.MANAGEDACCOUNT,
o.Name1, 
select * from 
    (select cast(cast dateyear*1000 + datemonth*100 + dateday as varchar(255)) as date as date1 from  <@Schema>.CampaignDates where datetype = 'Start' and campaignyear =   <@CampaignYear> and orgaccountnumber = v.MANAGEDACCOUNT) d1,
    (select cast(cast dateyear*1000 + datemonth*100 + dateday as varchar(255)) as date as date2 from  <@Schema>.CampaignDates where datetype = 'End' and campaignyear =     <@CampaignYear> and orgaccountnumber = v.MANAGEDACCOUNT) d2
from <@Schema>.VolunteerRelationships v
inner join <@Schema>.organizations o
on o.accountnumber=v.MANAGEDACCOUNT
where v.VOLUNTEERACCOUNT = <@SelectedInd> and ( v.EXPIRYDATE IS NULL OR v.EXPIRYDATE > <@Today> )
```

Comment: Why did you tag both mysql and sql-server?

Comment: @HoneyboyWilson fixed the tags.

Comment: But which DBMS are you using? SQL is just the query language and differs from DBMS to DBMS.

Comment: @HoneyboyWilson It's an old legacy CRM system (Andar 360) that has a query builder app. Please let me know if there's anything more specific I can provide to clear up any confusion.